# How do I re-write 3 for loops into one function

Tags: optimization, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I am building a color sorting machine using a Arduino uno and a TCS3200 color sensor. I have a code that is working perfectly fine however I feel like the code could be a bit more efficient seeing that I am using 3 almost identical for loops. Could anyone help me rewrite these 3 for loops into one loop. Thank you in advance!

Like I mentioned the code works perfectly fine. I only need some help re-writing these 3 for loops

```
void loop() {

  delay(150);
  float frequencyR[3];

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  delay(150);
  digitalWrite(S2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(S3, LOW);
  frequencyR[i] = pulseIn(sensorOut, LOW);

  delay(150);

  }
  float frequencyG[3];

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  delay(150);
  digitalWrite(S2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(S3, HIGH);
  frequencyG[i] = pulseIn(sensorOut, LOW);

  delay(150);

  }
  float frequencyB[3];

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  digitalWrite(S2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(S3, HIGH);
  frequencyB[i] = pulseIn(sensorOut, LOW);

  delay(150);

  }
```

:)

Comment: Post this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are measuring the same colour three times and then you go to the next colour. I am suggesting to measure every colour once per cycle and repeat it three times:

```
void loop() {

  delay(150);
  float frequencyR[3];
  float frequencyG[3];
  float frequencyB[3];

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    // red
    digitalWrite(S2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(S3, LOW);
    frequencyR[i] = pulseIn(sensorOut, LOW);
    delay(150);

    // green
    digitalWrite(S2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(S3, HIGH);
    frequencyG[i] = pulseIn(sensorOut, LOW);
    delay(150);

    // blue
    digitalWrite(S2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(S3, HIGH);
    frequencyB[i] = pulseIn(sensorOut, LOW);
    delay(150);

  }
}
```